# Can I use multiple instances of http://schema.org/Organization?

Tags: html, seo, schema.org, microdata

I have a website which list multiple companies, my markup goes something like this:

```
<h2>Checkout those cool companies</h2>
<div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
  <img itemprop="logo" src="logo1.jpg" alt="">
  <h3 itemprop="name">Company1</h3>
  <p itemprop="description">It's a great company</p>
  <span itemprop="url">http://company1.com</span>
</div>

<div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
  <img itemprop="logo" src="logo2.jpg" alt="">
  <h3 itemprop="name">Company2</h3>
  <p itemprop="description">It's a great company as well</p>
  <span itemprop="url">http://company2.com</span>
</div>

<div itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization">
  <img itemprop="logo" src="logo3.jpg" alt="">
  <h3 itemprop="name">Company3</h3>
  <p itemprop="description">It's a amazing company</p>
  <span itemprop="url">http://company3.com</span>
</div>
```

I'm using `itemtype="https://schema.org/Organization` multiples times in order to help crawler better identify the content.

1. Is this an appropriate use of `https://schema.org/Organization`?
2. How can I make my own `https://schema.org/Organization` not conflict with the companies markup I'm listing?

Comment: Note that you have to use a link element if the value of the `url` property should be a URL (instead of a string). So instead of `span`, you should use e.g. `a` (or `link`, if it shouldn’t be "clickable").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it’s correct to use multiple `Organization` items for this purpose.

To make clear that your own `Organization` is not part of this list, you could

- provide it as value for [`author`](http://schema.org/author)/[`publisher`](http://schema.org/publisher) (of the `WebPage`), and
- provide an [`ItemList`](http://schema.org/ItemList) for the list of the other organizations.

In case this list of organizations is the main content for that page, you could use `mainEntity` (for the `ItemList`) and use [`CollectionPage`](http://schema.org/CollectionPage) instead of `WebPage`:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/CollectionPage">

  <div itemprop="publisher" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
  </div>

  <section itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ItemList">
    <h2>Checkout those <span itemprop="name">cool companies</span></h2>
    <article itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"></article>
    <article itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"></article>
    <article itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization"></article>
  </section>

</body>
```