# Declaring ImageGallery properties from within an ImageObject: Can you nest an itemtype from its parent with a different itemtype?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

I’m new to Microdata and using Schema.org properties and have a question regarding the scope of `itemscope`.

I’m creating an `itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery"` in the `<main>` tag. Two of its properties are `mainContentOfPage` and `primaryImageOfPage`.

However when I use them nested inside of an `ImageObject` declaration, Google says:

> ImageObject is not a known valid target type for the mainContentOfPage  & primaryImageOfPage property.

Does each element NOT inherit the `itemscope` from its parent? Which seems to be the case, as I’m getting the above validation error from the Google testing tool.

Unfortunately the `ImageObject` doesn’t seem to use most of the `ImageGallery` properties.

Any pointers on what I’m doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<main itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
        <!-- Box 1 -->
        <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject" itemprop="workExample">
            <figure role="figure">
                <img id="id_BoxImage1" src="/images/nav/grid1.jpg" alt="{Caption}" role="img"  itemprop="image contentUrl"/>
                <figcaption itemprop="about">{Caption}</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </article>
        <!-- <article> Box 2 -->
        <!-- <article> Box 3 -->
        <!-- Box Main -->
        <article itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject" itemprop="mainContentOfPage workExample">
            <figure role="figure">
                <img itemprop="primaryImageOfPage image contentUrl"/>
                <figcaption itemprop="about">{Caption}</figcaption>
            </figure>
        </article>
        <!-- <article> Box 5 -->
        <!-- <article> Box 6 -->
    <!-- <article> Box 7 -->
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

`itemprop` applies to its nearest parent `itemscope`.

You can’t use properties of types that are applied to parent `itemscope`s, you can only use the properties of the type that is applied to the nearest parent `itemscope`.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
  <!-- you can only use 'Person' properties here -->

  <div itemprop="owns" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <!-- you can only use 'Product' properties here, 
         not 'Person' properties -->

    <div itemprop="manufacturer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
      <!-- you can only use 'Organization' properties here, 
           not 'Person'/'Product' properties -->
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
```

In your example, there are two separate issues with the use of Schema.org.

#### Schema.org: Range (values of a property)

Each Schema.org property has one or more *expected types*. For the [`mainContentOfPage` property](http://schema.org/mainContentOfPage), the expected type is `WebPageElement`.

In your example, you are adding `mainContentOfPage` to the `ImageGallery` (which is fine), and you provide an `ImageObject` value for `mainContentOfPage` (which is not fine). `WebPageElement` is not a parent type of `ImageObject`, so `ImageObject` is not an expected value. It’s technically/formally allowed, but Google’s SDTT typically recognizes the stated expected types and gives errors when using something else.

If you want to convey that the images are part of the image gallery, you could use Schema.org’s `hasPart` property:

```html
<main itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">

  <article itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject"></article>

</main>
```

(alternative to `hasPart`: [adding a list that contains all images (`mainEntity ItemList`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39403139/1591669))

#### Schema.org: Domain (properties of a type)

Each Schema.org property has one or more *types* to which it can be added. For the [`primaryImageOfPage`](http://schema.org/primaryImageOfPage) property, the type is `WebPage`.

In your example, you are adding the `primaryImageOfPage` property to an `ImageObject`, but `WebPage` is not a parent type of `ImageObject`.

`ImageGallery` can have the `primaryImageOfPage` property, because `ImageGallery` is a more specific `WebPage`. So if you want to convey that one of the images in the gallery is the primary image, you could use:

```html
<main itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">

  <article itemprop="hasPart primaryImageOfPage" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject"></article>

  <article itemprop="hasPart" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject"></article>

</main>
```